# Unable to cast Callback object to type System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-client

I trying to disconnect client to server:

```
if (((ICommunicationObject)proxy).State == CommunicationState.Opened)
{
   proxy.DisConnect();
}
```

It can't be casting proxy of type (ServiceCallback) that implements (IServiceCallback) as ServiceContract to type ICommunicationObject , it returns null

```
 public class ServiceCallback : IServiceCallback , IDisposable { /* Implementation */ }
```

Exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Partition.ServiceCallback' to type 'System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ServiceCallback` class needs to implement `System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject`
If it doesn't, like in your case, the casting will fail.